# mod_rewrite exclude multiple words

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm going to implement a "pretty rewrite" redirect solution through htaccess and mod_rewrite. What I want to achieve is the following:

```
example.com/test123 --> example.com/page.php?c=test123
```

This is easily done with a single `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) page.php?c=$1 [L,NC]
```

But I want to exclude some urls:

- `/` (I've got a specific index.php that I don't want to be rewritten)
- `css/(.*)`
- `images/(.*)`
- `CMS/(.*)`
- `js/(.*)`
- `contact/(.*)`
- `prijslijst/(.*)`
- `werk/(.*)`

I've tried some regex, but so far with no avail. I would like some help to make sure that the listed directories do not get rewritten, but any other keyword is rewritten.

---

**Some things I've tried:**

*The following excerpts cancel any rewriting:*

The first one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^!prijslijst/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^!werk/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^!js/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^!css/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^!CMS/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^!images/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^!contact/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteRule ^(.*) page.php?c=$1 [L,NC]
```

The second one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^!(prijslijst|werk|js|css|CMS|images|contact)/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteRule ^(.*) page.php?c=$1 [L,NC]
```

The third one:

```
RewriteRule ^!(prijslijst|werk|js|css|CMS|images|contact)/{0,1}(.*) page.php?c=$1 [L,NC]
```

*A slight adjustment of the top one resulted in **everything** being rewritten, even the stuff I wanted to exclude:*

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!prijslijst/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!werk/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!js/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!css/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!CMS/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!images/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!contact/{0,1}(.*)"
RewriteRule ^(.*) page.php?c=$1 [L,NC]
```

(`^` was removed from the start of every second parameter of `RewriteCond`)

---

**EDIT**

I've submitted an answer of my own to document the final solution. @ndn's answer was of great influence, it gave me a push in the right direction. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution** (with thanks to @ndn)

@ndn gave me a starting point to find the right solution. I'd like to thank him for giving me a pointer in the right direction!

In the end, I reduced the amount of `RewriteCond`s. Unlike @ndn sugggested, I did not go for a negative regex in the `RewriteRule`. I think it gives a better overview to use `RewriteCond`s for constraining the rewriting, but it can be done within both `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond`, it's a matter of preference.

So what did I end up with? Here it is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ut-taertje/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ut-taertje/(?:.{0}$|css|CMS|js|images|prijslijst|contact|werk)(?:$|/.*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ut-taertje/(?:page\.php|index\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?c=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I'll explain it shortly. I did not include the `RewriteBase` in the question, but given the fact it plays a part in the `RewriteCond`, it would clarify it better. Replace the subdirectory `/ut-taertje/` with `/` to make it apply to the root.

So I put my rewriting constraints into two `RewriteCond`s. The upper one is a regex group to exclude the various directories I wanted to exclude. Note that the group includes `.{0}$`, as it should also exclude the root of the directory itself, which does not have anything after the leading `/` of the request URI. Next to that, I have a second regex group (`(?:$|/.*)?`) which enables me to exclude not only the directories themselves, but also anything that comes after the slash (not only `js/`, but also `js/codebase.js` or `js/jquery/`).

The second `RewriteCond` is to exclude an edge case. When testing, I used `301` redirects, rather than "invisible" redirects. It appeared that rewriting to `page.php?c=<the original request URI>` triggered an infinite loop of redirect requests from the server. Why? Because it was not part of the exclusion from the first `RewriteCond`!

So that's it. The `RewriteRule` is rather simple, it rewrites anything that passes the conditional filters from both `RewriteCond`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^(?!/$|css/|images/|CMS/|js/|contact/|prijslijst/|werk/)(.*) page.php?c=$1 [L,NC]
```

Basically, I just took your original rewrite and added negative lookahead for the list of things you wanted skipped `(?!/$|css/|images/|CMS/|js/|contact/|prijslijst/|werk/)`.

Comment: On second thought, something does not work yet. It's the `/$` that is not respected yet. It means that `example.com/` still gets redirected to `example.com/page.php`. All the other ones do get excluded, so that part works fine (css, images, etcetera).

Comment: @Jeroen, could you try replacing `/$` with `/?$`?

Comment: replacing `/$` with `$` didn't work (I added a comment before testing it properly, apologies).

Comment: It didn't work. I decided to seek help with someone else offline. He pointed out some things on mod_rewrite and regex negative lookaheads. We were able to adjust the regex query, which ended up as follows: `(?:.{0}|css|CMS|js|images|prijslijst|contact|werk)(?:$|/.*)$`. This one accounts for only a `/`, any of the directories to avoid rewriting, and whether the directories have a trailing `/` or not. Ultimately, I chose for `RewriteCond` to constrain the rewriting before the actual rewriting, but the regex would also fit in place of the negative lookahead regex you wrote.